# SetEnvIf problem on htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, setenv

I'm trying to get this running,

```
SetEnvIf Host ^dev\. HOST_DEVELOPMENT
SetEnvIf Host ^www\. HOST_PRODUCTION

<IfDefine HOST_DEVELOPMENT>

    # e.g. php_flag display_errors on 

</IfDefine>

<IfDefine HOST_PRODUCTION>

    # e.g. php_flag display_errors off

</IfDefine>
```

but it doesn't work. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<IfDefine>` only runs when apache starts.  The `HOST_*` variables should be available in your PHP script, so you can check `$_ENV['HOST_PRODUCTION']` and turn `display_errors` off at run time.